# How to inject single json parameter value in @PostMapping

Tags: java, json, spring, spring-web

I have a simple `POST` servlet and want to inject only one single property of a `JSON` request:

```
@RestController
public class TestServlet {
    @PostMapping(value = "/test", consumes = APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE)
    public String test(@Valid @NotBlank @RequestBody String test) {
        return test;
    }
}
```

Request:

```
{
    "test": "random value",
    "some": "more"
}
```

Result: the `test` parameter contains the whole json, not the parameter value only. Why? How can I achieve this *without* having to introduce an extra Bean?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can't expect Spring to guess that you want to parse the json to extract the "test" field.

If you don't want an extra bean, use a `Map<String, String>` and get the value with "test" key :

```
@RestController
public class TestServlet {
    @PostMapping(value = "/test", consumes = APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE)
    public String test(@Valid @NotBlank @RequestBody Map<String, String> body) {
        return body.get("test");
    }
}
```